# Yahoo weather and Android

Tags: java, android

I am working on app where I am loading weather from Yahoo. From their XML I am getting "text", "code", "temp". What I want to do is based on code load image and display it. Code range is from 00-47 and I use [those amazing icons](http://merlinthered.deviantart.com/art/plain-weather-icons-157162192). Now I know I can load image using this way:

```
if (code == 0){
    ImageView imageDisplay = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.weatherImg);
    imageDisplay.setImageResource(R.Drawable.weather_00)

} else if (code == 1) {
}
```

But this is not a great solution, than I have 100+ lines of code of if else statement. My idea was to do it this way:

```
for(int i = 0;i<48;i++){
    if(weatherCode == i){
         String imgName = "R.Drawable.weather_" + i;
    }
```

but I cannot use String with "Drawable" it has to be Drawable... Does anybody know how to dynamically change name of the image based on a code I am using?

Comment: What about putting the drawable ids in an array and getting the index from weatherCode?

Comment: Good idea, I was thinking about that, I'll give it a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved it this way:

```
String imgName = "weather_" + i;
ImageView imageDisplay = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.weatherImg);
imageDisplay.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(getResources().getIdentifier(imgName, "drawable", getPackageName())));
```